# How to create dataframe using two dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe 'df1' and 'df2'

```
df1=   a       b
       1       such as
       2       who I'm

df2=   a       keyword
       1       such
       1       as
       2       who
       2       I'm
```

Based on this two dataframe I want to create following dataframe

```
result =   a           keyword
           such as     such
           such as     as
           who I'm     who
           who I'm     I'm
```

Comment: Can you provide the constructors for your two dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, just perform a replacement with `map`:

```
df2['a'] = df2['a'].map(df1.set_index('a')['b'])
```